# Write PnP PowerShell log file

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, logfile

I have a PnP PowerShell script for which log file has to be written with some specific details in Excel file

I have tried some simple ways like start-transcript but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Export-CSV function to write to CSV/Excel file. First create a variable and then write your logs to the variable finally export it to CSV. See example below:

```
$logData = @()
$logData += New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
"DateTime" = $someDateValue
"Message" = $logMessage
})
$logData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "c:\temp\log.csv"
```